# Nodejs: How to refuse connection in SNI callback?

Tags: node.js, https

I'm currently using Node.js v7.7.2. Here is my simplified https server setup:

```
const branyaContext = tls.createSecureContext({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/ecdsa.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/chained.pem')
});


const options = {
    SNICallback: function (domain, cb) {
        if ((domain === 'branya.cat') || (domain === 'www.branya.cat')) {
            cb(null, branyaContext);
        }
    },
    ciphers: [
        "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
        "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA",
        "!RC4",
        "!AES256"
    ].join(':'),
    honorCipherOrder: true
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(8000);
```

When I try to curl my server with (DNS was already pointing my test domain to my IP)

```
curl https://test.branya.cat/ --head -v
```

The connection seems to be stuck at

```
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
```

So, my question is:

1. As a server, is it better to leave the connection open until the timeout expired or close it immediately?
2. How do I refuse such connection?

**Answered:**

Thanks to the robertklep comment. Now I change the SNICallback to:

```
if ((domain === 'branya.cat') || (domain === 'www.branya.cat')) {
    cb(null, branyaContext);
} else {
    cb();
}
```

Which will cause the invalid connection to close immediately with:

```
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

The connection on the server side also closed properly. (I checked with server.getConnections).

Also, according to robertklep's comment, it's the best practice to close the connection to prevent DoS attack.

Comment: What happens if you call the callback with a non-falsy first argument? Say `cb(Error('connection refused'))`?

Comment: FWIW, I would definitely close it explicitly from the server, instead of having it linger and time out (not only would it be a great way to DoS your server if you let them linger, it's also better practise to close a connection if you can).