# node.js : Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, openssl

I was have my ipn paypal my-prvkey.pem , my-pubcert.pem

like that and there was no problems

```
var httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./app/certsandkeys/my-prvkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./app/certsandkeys/my-pubcert.pem'),

    requestCert: true


}
```

but after i added my site cert and keys that's created by openssl like that to my code

```
var httpsOptions = {
    key: [fs.readFileSync('./app/certsandkeys/my-prvkey.pem'),fs.readFileSync('./app/certsandkeys/ssl/server.key')],
    cert: [fs.readFileSync('./app/certsandkeys/my-pubcert.pem'),fs.readFileSync('./app/certsandkeys/ssl/server.crt')],

    requestCert: true


}
```

now i get this error and i don't know why

Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch

Comment: I dont know how node.js sets up the keys,but the error is shown in X509_check_private_key,it is indicating the public and private keys passed to it are not consistent ie they dont have same modulus and exponent

Comment: Have you tried checking the certificates formats? openssl rsa -noout -text -in my-prvkey.pem openssl x509 -noout -text -in my-pubcert.pem! It private key might be rsa and server certificate is x509 forrmat

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs for options.key](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options):

> Multiple keys using **different** algorithms can be provided either as an
>   array of unencrypted key strings or ...

The [tests](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/test/parallel/test-tls-multi-key.js) use RSA and Eliptic Curve.. You almost certainly have and want two of the same algorithm keys, and it wont help you to use different algorithms since you have no way of knowing what a client will end up negotiating.

As in [my answer for your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57564575/1269466), if you want different clients to get different key/chains then you may do so on the domain name using SNI and give the clients their respective hosts in URLs. There's no way to get client to examine two chains and then tell your sever which key to use.